# Bind Fastclick to new dynamically created elements with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova

I am using Fastclick (https://github.com/ftlabs/fastclick) for a Phonegap application that is written entirely in js, mainly jQuery. I use Fastclick to eliminate the 300ms delay iOS adds to the normal on click. It works perfectly.

My only issue has been with trying to figure out to bind Fastclick functionality to dynamic elements that are created after the initial page load.

This is how Fastclick is first attached:

```
$(function() {
    FastClick.attach(document.body);
});
```

and then everytime I use a normal jQuery click event on an original element, it just works.

```
$(".original-element").click(function() {
   // Just works!
});
```

I want to be able to do the same thing on new elements that get created via JS as the app gets used. For instance:

```
$(body).append("<button id="new-btn">Press me</button>");

$("#new-btn").click(function() {
  // Please help me work with Fastclick
});
```

So basically, I just need to know how to bind Fastclick onto new elements after they are dynamically added to the DOM. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Haven't verified, but from the code it looks like it should work. Check `FastClick.prototype.needsClick` method. Never used Phonegap, is there a way to replicate the issue easily?

Comment: .needsclick removes fastclick functionality from an element. I need to add the functinality to an element.
I'll try to set us a jsFiddle to replicate the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you are done creating new elements just reinstantiate fastclick

```
new FastClick(document.body);
```

Comment: Does this automatically destroy the last instance?

Comment: This shouldn't be necessary, FastClick automatically affects newly created elements: https://github.com/ftlabs/fastclick/issues/273